Cell editing do not work when dataTable and columns are dynamically generated
I have a web application using Primefaces 12. When I use the dataTable in a xhtml file, do work fine if I fill one of the columns and go to another. But when I use the dataTable dynamically generated does not work, do not enter in on onEditarCeldaTablaProc method and also it is showed next error:
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent.resolveValue(CellEditEvent.java:106)
at org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent.\<init\>(CellEditEvent.java:58)
at org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent.\<init\>(CellEditEvent.java:62)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.queueEvent(DataTable.java:452)
at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:55)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:134)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.decodeBehaviors(ComponentUtils.java:256)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:628)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:75)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:533)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:140)
at     com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:629)
at    com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:715)

This is the content of the xhtml file that works fine:
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:toolbar id="tabla_BotoneraTablaProc" styleClass="toolbar-estilo-tabla-form-solicitud">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:outputLabel value="Pruebas" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <p:tooltip for="botonAnadirFilaTablaProc"
                value="#{etiquetasSubvenciones['anadir.fila']}" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade" hideEvent="mouseleave click"/>
            <p:commandButton id="botonAnadirFilaTablaProc" styleClass="boton"
                icon="fas fa-plus"
                action="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onNuevaFilaTablaPruebaUno}"
                update="@([id$=tablaPrueba])"
                process="@this">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    value="formFichaSolicitud:fichaSolicitud:tablaPrueba"
                    target="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.idDataTableActual}" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:tooltip for="botonEliminarFilaTablaProc"
                value="#{etiquetasSubvenciones['borrar.fila']}" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade" hideEvent="mouseleave click"/>
            <p:commandButton id="botonEliminarFilaTablaProc" styleClass="boton"
                icon="fas fa-minus" 
                action="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onEliminarFilaTablaProc}">
                <p:confirm header="#{etiquetas['eliminar.titulo']}"
                    message="#{etiquetas['eliminar.mensaje']}"
                    icon="ui-icon-alert" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</f:facet>

<p:dataTable id="tablaPruebaUno" widgetVar="tablaPruebaUno" var="listaColsTablaProc"
    value="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.lstPruebaUno}"
    lazy="false"
    rowKey="#{listaColsTablaProc.hashCode()}"
    selection="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.pruebaSeleccionadaUno}"
    emptyMessage="#{etiquetas['emptyMessage']}" reflow="true"
    editable="true" editMode="cell">

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onEditarCeldaTablaProc}"/>

    <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:4%;text-align:center"/>                           

    <p:column
        headerText="Columna1" style="text-align:center">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="listaColsTablaCol1" value="#{listaColsTablaProc.id}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{listaColsTablaProc.id}" style="width: 100%;">
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column
        headerText="Columna2" style="text-align:center">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText id="listaColsTablaCol2" value="#{listaColsTablaProc.nombre}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{listaColsTablaProc.nombre}" style="width: 100%;">
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

And this is the code of the part that's implemented dynamically:
Attributes:
private static final String EVT_AJAX_CELL_EDIT = "cellEdit";

AjaxBehavior pAjaxCellEdit;

String idDataTableActual;

List<Prueba> lstPrueba;
Prueba pruebaSeleccionada;

List<Prueba> lstPruebaUno;
Prueba pruebaSeleccionadaUno;

..............
In constructor:
pAjaxCellEdit = new AjaxBehavior();
MethodExpression meEditCell = expFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onEditarCeldaTablaProc}", getClass(), new Class<?>[] {CellEditEvent.class});
pAjaxCellEdit.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(meEditCell, meEditCell));

In another method:
tab.getChildren().add(toolBarCumplimentarDos("TablaPrueba", "1", PANEL_BOT_TBL_FORM_SOLICITUD, TOOLBAR_TBL_FORM_SOLICITUD));
tab.getChildren()
        .add(dataTableCumplimentarDos(
                "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.lstPrueba}",
                "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.pruebaSeleccionada}",
                lstPrueba));

Methods called:
private Panel toolBarCumplimentarDos(String titulo, String idTabla, String estiloPanel, String estiloToolBar) {
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Toolbar toolBar = new Toolbar();
    ToolbarGroup toolBarGroupTitle= new ToolbarGroup();
    ToolbarGroup toolBarGroupButtons= new ToolbarGroup();
    OutputLabel outputLabel = new OutputLabel();
    Tooltip tooltipAdd = new Tooltip();
    Tooltip tooltipDel = new Tooltip();
    CommandButton comButAdd = new CommandButton();
    CommandButton comButDel = new CommandButton();
    ValueExpression target = expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.idDataTableActual}", String.class);
    ValueExpression value = expFactory.createValueExpression(TABVIEW_SOLICITUDES + TABVIEW_BLOQUE_DATOS + ":" + TBL_SOLICITUD_PREF_ID_DT + idTabla, String.class);
    ActionListener handler = new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target , value);
    
    tooltipAdd.setFor(PREF_ETQ_BOTON_ANADIR_FILA + idTabla);
    tooltipAdd.setValue(VALUE_TOOLTIP_BOTON_ANADIR_FILA);
    tooltipAdd.setShowEffect(SHOWEF_TOOLTIP);
    tooltipAdd.setHideEffect(HIDEEF_TOOLTIP);
    
    comButAdd.setId(PREF_ETQ_BOTON_ANADIR_FILA + idTabla);
    comButAdd.setIcon(ICONO_ANADIR);
    comButAdd.setStyleClass("boton");
    comButAdd.setActionExpression(expFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onNuevaFilaTablaPrueba}", getClass(), new Class[0]));
    comButAdd.addActionListener(handler);
    comButAdd.setUpdate("@([id$=" + TBL_SOLICITUD_PREF_ID_DT + idTabla + "])");
    comButAdd.setProcess("@this");

    tooltipDel.setFor(PREF_ETQ_BOTON_BORRAR_FILA + idTabla);
    tooltipDel.setValue(VALUE_TOOLTIP_BOTON_BORRAR_FILA);
    tooltipDel.setShowEffect(SHOWEF_TOOLTIP);
    tooltipDel.setHideEffect(HIDEEF_TOOLTIP);

    comButDel.setId(PREF_ETQ_BOTON_BORRAR_FILA + idTabla);
    comButDel.setIcon(ICONO_ELIMINAR);
    comButDel.setStyleClass("boton");
    comButDel.setActionExpression(expFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.onEliminarFilaTablaProc}", getClass(), new Class[0]));
    comButDel.setValueExpression("disabled", expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{fichaFormularioConvocatoriaBean.listaBloquesDatosFormularioCumplimentar.get(0).getObjetos().get(0).tablaBloqueDatosDto.detalles.filaSeleccionada == null}", Boolean.class));

    outputLabel.setValue(titulo);
    toolBarGroupTitle.getChildren().add(outputLabel);
    toolBarGroupButtons.getChildren().add(tooltipAdd);
    toolBarGroupButtons.getChildren().add(comButAdd);
    toolBarGroupButtons.getChildren().add(tooltipDel);
    toolBarGroupButtons.getChildren().add(comButDel);
    toolBar.getChildren().add(toolBarGroupTitle);
    toolBar.getChildren().add(toolBarGroupButtons);
    toolBar.setStyleClass(estiloToolBar);
    panel.setStyleClass(estiloPanel);
    panel.getFacets().put("header", toolBar);

    return panel;
}


private DataTable dataTableCumplimentarDos(String filasValueExpr, String filaSeleccionadaValueExpr, List<Prueba> tabla) {
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    List<UIColumn> columnas = new ArrayList<UIColumn>();
    CellEditor cellEd = new CellEditor();
    Column colUI;
    String var = TBL_SOLICITUD_PREF_VAR + "1";
    String idDataTable = TBL_SOLICITUD_PREF_ID_DT + "1";
    
    colUI = new Column();
    colUI.setSelectionMode(TBL_SOLICITUD_SEL_MODE);
    colUI.setStyle(TBL_SOLICITUD_SEL_STYLE);
    columnas.add(colUI);
    
    cellEd.getFacets().put("output", outputLabelCumplimentar("#{" + var + ".id}",""));
    
    cellEd.getFacets().put("input", uiComponentCumplimentarDos(TipoDato.EnumTipoDato.ENTERO, "#{" + var + "", ".id}", null, true));

    colUI = new Column();
    colUI.setStyle(TBL_SOLICITUD_CELL_STYLE);
    colUI.setHeaderText("Columna1");
    colUI.getChildren().add(cellEd);
    columnas.add(colUI);
    
    cellEd = new CellEditor();      

    cellEd.getFacets().put("output", outputLabelCumplimentar("#{" + var + ".nombre}",""));
    
    cellEd.getFacets().put("input", uiComponentCumplimentarDos(TipoDato.EnumTipoDato.ENTERO, "#{" + var + "", ".nombre}", null, true));

    colUI = new Column();
    colUI.setStyle(TBL_SOLICITUD_CELL_STYLE);
    colUI.setHeaderText("Columna2");
    colUI.getChildren().add(cellEd);
    columnas.add(colUI);

    dataTable.setColumns(columnas);
    dataTable.setValueExpression("value", expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, filasValueExpr, ArrayList.class));
    dataTable.setLazy(false);
    dataTable.setEditable(true);
    dataTable.setEditMode("cell");
    dataTable.setVar(var);
    dataTable.setEmptyMessage(TBL_MSG_VACIA);
    dataTable.setReflow(true);
    dataTable.setValueExpression("rowKey", expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + var + ".hashCode()}", String.class));
    dataTable.setValueExpression("selection", expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, filaSeleccionadaValueExpr, ArrayList.class));
    dataTable.setId(idDataTable);
    dataTable.setWidgetVar(idDataTable);
    dataTable.addClientBehavior(EVT_AJAX_CELL_EDIT, pAjaxCellEdit);
    
    return dataTable;
}

Could you help me, please?
Thanks in advance
I am trying to implement cell edition with dynamic dataTables generated. And I expect someone can help me.

I have just discovered that when I create the table dynamically, the "data-rk" on the rows is not generated. Only the "data-ri" is generated, but not the "data-rk". Why?

I have finally found the problem. Columns must be added to dataTable as children, not using dataTable.setColumns(columnas). So dataTable.getChildren().add(colUI) is the solution.

I have finally found the problem. Columns must be added to dataTable as children, not using dataTable.setColumns(columnas). So dataTable.getChildren().add(colUI) is the solution.
